# What network does a datastore (Esx 4) copy use?

Tags: vmware-esx, datastore

First a brief description of my environment. I have 4 VMware ESX 4 clusters that I manage with one VC server. Each server has 6 NICs. 2 for iSCSI back to a EMC CX4, 2 for the Vm port groups and 2 for Vmotion and service console. Each server has several datastores on the CX4. Each cluster has its on CX4.Each cluster is totally separate with the only common ground being the VC box.

My question is if I copy files, in this case a template, by browsing a datastore on one cluster and coping to a datastore on another, what network does this copy? Service console? VC box? Vmmotion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the service-console/management-network - no other way if you're using the DS browser.